# Why does my code ignore a true if-condition?

Tags: c#

I've got the following code:

```
    private static void checkCodesInPlayerCenter(GameObject player)
    {
        Vector2 collisionCenter = player.GetCollisionCenter(player.PublicCollisionRectangle);

        if (TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter) == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter).Codes.Count; ++i )
```

It is possible that sometimes the object I get from GetMapSquareAtPixel is null. To not cause a NullReferenceException in the for-loop I decided to check is its null, and if so end the function early, however it seems to completely ignore the if-condition, even if the object returned is null.
I've set a breakpoint on the return statement but the code never goes there and instead triggers the NullReferenceException I tried to avoid.

Any help please?

Comment: Maybe `TileMap` is null. Possibly?  Or `codes`?  Or `player`?

Comment: Could it be collisionCenter that's null?

Comment: Did you get any result when first line inside the method invoke ?

Comment: Are you sure that the following method GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter) does not get caught by an Exception before it returns 'anything' at all?

Answer (score 2):

It's probable that

```
TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter)
```

is not null, but

```
TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter).Codes
```

is. If that's the case then

```
TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter).Codes.Count
```

will fail with NullReferenceException.

You need to add that to your guard conditional:

```
    if (TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter) == null ||
        TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter).Codes == null)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: this and @anthony-sottile 's solutions were the right ones.
Basicly the first call (when checking) never returned null (as it should be the case) but I indeed actually changed the Elements in the Codes list and didnt know a list would automaticly become null if it has no more elements in it after removing the last one. So it actually triggered the NRE sometimes during the loop, after the last code was removed (it doesn't always remove them)

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

what if the function returns two different results (unlikely but don't call this possible expensive function twice anyhow - save the result in a variable and check/use this variable)

What if the .Codes part is null - check this as well!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the return value of the function changes between the two conditions?

Try assigning to a local variable and doing your check (and step through with the debugger)

```
private static void checkCodesInPlayerCenter(GameObject player)
{
    Vector2 collisionCenter = player.GetCollisionCenter(player.PublicCollisionRectangle);

    var squareAtPixel = TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel(collisionCenter);

    if (squareAtPixel  == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < squareAtPixel.Codes.Count; ++i )
```

This is also possibly better if the GetMapSquareAtPixel call is expensive (one call vs two calls when all you really care about is a null check)

EDIT: Which variable is it attempting to get at when the NRE is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to assign TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel return value to some local variable and after check it against null condition and use the same var in for loop.

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the method you're calling is mutating state (which generally a getter *shouldn't* do), then it could be that it's not an idempotent call, meaning it's not safe to call more than once.

Additionally, adding that expression in the debugger is quite possibly causing it to be evaluated before you step into your code, resulting in the NPE.

I would advocate trying to store the value of TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel in a separate variable.